# GMAIL ACCOUNT - Technical details of permanent failure: Message rejected.

Tags: gmail, message

Since last one week I am having issue of not sending emails through my gmail google app for business. Every time I sent mail it gives me following error. Sometimes it works well but then for 24 hours it gets block. I tried all google support links still issue remains same.

Strange Point:

Our other email address from same domain working well.

Mail Delivery Subsystem 
4:09 PM (19 minutes ago)

to me 
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

```
 ****@****.com
```

Technical details of permanent failure:
Message rejected.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more

Message-ID:

Comment: Did you read the link? Did you notice the explanation of possible causes there, if you are using it legitimately? You say you used the Google support contact link there; did you get a response? What more do you think we can add that Google support can't?

Comment: Sorry Google support means online tutorial they provided. I tried all but nothing worked out. I already have set this. 

Configure SPF records to work with Google Apps - Google Apps ...
Authenticate email with DKIM - Google Apps Administrator Help

Comment: By Google support I mean Google support: "If you are sending mail in accordance with our guidelines and Gmail continues to mark your messages as spam, [contact us](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/request.py?hl=en&bug_topic=69585&ctx=gtag_headers&contact_type=gtag_headers)."

Comment: Let me send them too. Thanks buddy.